# Angular reactive form setting value with HTML string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to set a string value to the control with `patchValue` method. The string value contains HTML tags but the HTML tags are translated as plain text for some reason.

```
<textarea rows="5" name="myField" formControlName="myField" readonly></textarea>

const htmlStr = '<p>HTML Content HERE</p>'
// assuming the form group instance already created
this.form.get('myField').patchValue(this.htmlStr);
```

The Angular API doc didn't say too much about how [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#patchvalue) can handle the HTML value and is pretty generic though.

Comment: So you know about the `[innerHTML]=htmlStr` binding? Just want to do it through Reactive form?

Comment: @AshishRanjan yes, I do, but would like to see if it's possible to do it via Reactive approach

Comment: What does your form model look like, are you sure your FormGroup's controls{} has `myField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Html String to a textArea will always show up as plain Html in the textarea.

The `[innerHTML]` can only be applied to span/div or paragraph elements. You can not expect a html tag to show up as  or  (as it appears in HTML page mark up), if used inside a input field. it will always appear raw.

> Having said that, You can always patch a HTML string to your textarea
>   but do not expect it to display as HTML mark up with all the styles
>   etc.

You can check this  [stackBlitz  here for example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oztfbu)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are passing a type [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and not a [DOM element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp).

Example:

```
var domElementP         = document.createElement("p");
domElementP.textContent = 'TEXT HERE';
this.form.get('myField').patchValue(this.domElementP);
```

Libraries like `jQuery` allow easier creation of DOM elements.

For example:

```
// we assume that jQuery was loaded
var stringDOM = '<p>' +
  '<span>HTML Content HERE <i class="icon"></i></span>' +
'</p>';
var $jQueryObject            = $.parseHTML(stringDOM);
var domElement               = $jQueryObject[0];
this.form.get('myField').patchValue(this.domElement);
```